# Intellisense not providing available methods or documentation for Python3

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am using a Mac and trying to set up Intellisense in VS Code, and have followed the instructions to install the extension for Python. However, if I write a simple class and method with documentation attached to it, and then I later try and invoke the method (i.e. a.say_hello()), when I type in "a." I do not get the available options (i.e. say_hello), nor do I get the associated documentation (this prints out hello) attached to this function. How do I enable this?

```
class SimpleTest:
    def say_hello(self):
        '''
        this prints out hello
        '''
        print('hello')

a = SimpleTest()
a.say_hello()
```

Comment: Hi, which documentation did you followed? I tried to follow this doc: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python, install the Python 3.7.1 from https://www.python.org/downloads/ and install the python extension. Then type your shared code and it works fine as your expected: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Atv5QNuFrncKmE6h5OfOB16YYwvJ

Comment: The Python extension then provides shortcuts to run Python source code in the currently selected interpreter, we need to type Python: Select Interpreter in the Command Palette to switch to the python interpreter.